# TSLint Error "Exceeds maximum line length of 250"

Tags: angular, tslint

TS lint gives me error `TSLint Error "Exceeds maximum line length of 250` and for that reason m pipeline is failing on gitlab. I searched for this problem on google and every answer I got was for how to disable this rule.

But i don't want to disable this rule. On first place, i don't know why i get this error because my imported file does not have more than 250 lines of code.

So i have in my app.component.ts

```
 constructor(private securityClassesBuilder: SecurityClassesBuilderService) {};

myFunctionWhereIUseTheServic() {
   // TS LINT GIVES ME ERROR ON THIS LINE OF CODE
   this.securityClassesBuilder.getAllClasses();
}
```

but inside security classes builder service i don't have 250 lines of code

```
constructor(private shareService: ShareService, private translationService: TranslationService) { }

getAllClasses() {
}
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not 250 lines of code, this is a line of more than 250 characters.

Just format your file correctly and everything should go away.